# How to print a specific line (variable included) from a file (text) using cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing, cmd

I am really confused with something. I am making a batch file that can can display a specific line that I want. For example there is file `hi.txt`

Content of file  -

```
ro.build.id=KOT49H
ro.build.display.id=XXX_ROM_v1
ro.build.version.incremental=eng.mudingyu.1408084583
ro.custom.build.version=XOLO_8x-1000_0815.v009
ro.internal.version=J608_XOLO_N1A_V0.8.7_S08015
ro.internal.version.rgk=J608_XOLO_N1A_V0.8.7_S08015
ro.build.version.sdk=19
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.release=4.4.4
ro.build.date=Fri Aug 15 14:39:45 CST 2014
ro.build.date.utc=1408084785
```

As here you can see the file content. Now say I want to print **ONLY** this piece of information on my screen when batch is executed

> "4.4.4" from this line "ro.build.version.release=4.4.4"

I managed to pull of code for the 2nd line

```
ro.build.display.id=XXX_ROM_v1
```

When I execute batch I see this

> XXX_ROM_V1

Code I used

```
set "build.prop="
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%i in (WORKING_FOLDER\system\build.prop) do if not 
defined build.prop set "build.prop=%%i"
echo.
echo "%build.prop%"
echo.
echo Enter the name you want to choose
set /p name=
echo Backing up old build.prop...
md C:\Kitchen\temp
copy C:\Kitchen\WORKING_FOLDER\system\build.prop C:\Kitchen\temp
cd C:\Kitchen\temp
cd C:\Kitchen\WORKING_FOLDER\system
build.prop.new (
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in (build.prop) do (
   if "%%A" == "ro.build.display.id" (
     echo ro.build.display.id=%name%
   ) else (
     echo %%A=%%B
   )
 )
)
move /y build.prop.new build.prop >nul
build.prop.new (
  for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in (build.prop) do (
    if "%%A" == "ro.build.id" (
     echo ro.build.id=%name%
   ) else (
     echo %%A=%%B
   )
 )
)
move /y C:\Kitchen\temp\build.prop.new 
C:\Kitchen\WORKING_FOLDER\system\build.prop >nul
echo Changed value of ro.build.display.id to " %name% "
echo.
set "build.prop="
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%i in (WORKING_FOLDER\system\build.prop) do if not 
defined build.prop set "build.prop=%%i"
echo In build.prop now the current name of ROM is
echo.
echo Current ROM Name = %name%
```

Here as you see in first line I print the name using the line command function and also took input from user to change the name so it became easy to print the file name but in some other files the line "ro.build.display.id" is not always on 4th.
So my question is what logic or whatever can be done in order to print the particular term on screen that I wish to print **without** prompting user to enter new file name just print that specific piece of information

eg The OUTPUT I want

> The Android version is "4.4.4"

EG Say I want to print "4.4.4" only from the file above
how can I do it?
Using findstr or anything please help really appreciated.

Comment: It's only been 10 minutes. Be patient; you could be waiting for hours before you receive any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whew - that was a lot to read for a quite simple question.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('find "ro.build.version.release" hi.txt') do set release=%%i
echo The Android version is "%release%"
```

Find the correct line and tokenize it with `=` as delimiter.

Comment: My my I am sorry! I am not that good in windows scripting. I am new to all of this Sorry for writing too long. Will try and report

Comment: @Ramen: a good question maximizes the chances for a good and quick answer. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! It worked! :D I will keep in mind next time posting! One more quick thing is there any possiblity that the code reads the variable and prints the text like it searchs whole document for the line that has ro.build.version.release and gets correct line itself

Comment: There is no chance to alter a file directly with pure batch. But you can use a temporary file. Take a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21436542/2152082). Both answers are fine ( even if none of them is accepted or upvoted).